# rails convert or deal with #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0xe7ff39c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am writing a query which fetch some records based on the some condition but i am getting  `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000107609598>` object from query and when that object is get passed to controller its giving error like

```
undefined method `includes' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000107609598>.
```

I am writing query like

```
   scope :with_account_terms, ->(current_terms){
    where{|i|  i.terms.include? current_terms}
  }
```

Here terms is method in model which is returning terms related to user.

So this query is returning object of type  `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000107609598>`

How can I convert this to simple object like `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` or i can change my query.

Comment: Why are you passing a block to `where`?

Comment: because there are multiple records need to be check if these contains that terms..

Comment: Not sure that you're trying to do, but this isn't valid activerecord. Perhaps you're thinking of a different ORM